# how to compare a string with each element of a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi everyone im doing a little assignment in python and I need to do the following thing:
i have directories like /home/user/music, /home/user/photos and the like witch are inserted by the user and each new folder is a level so what i need to do is to create a method that recieves a number and then prints every folder that is at that level.

So far I have the creation of the list but i don't know how i can count every single "/" in the strings that are added via keyboard and have them stored so i can know the levels and then compare them with the number the program recieves.

If anybody can give me at least some basic idea of where to start I will be very greatful. Thanks in advance

I want to do something like this (pseudo-code)

```
example of some strings:
/home/user/music
/home/user/photos
/home/user/research
/home/user/music/rock

n=raw_input
if n is equal to a specific amount of "/":
print "every string that has the same amount of "/"
```

FULL CODE SO FAR

```
print "Please add paths"
l1=raw_input("> ")
l2=raw_input("> ")
while True:
        if l2 == "//":
            break
        else:
            l1=l1+"\n"
            l1=l1+l2
            l2=raw_input("> ")
l1=l1.split("\n")
print "Your paths are"
print "\n"
print "\n" .join(l1)
print "\n"
print l1[1].count("/")

while True:
    print "Choose an option "
    print "1. Amount of sub folders of a path"
    print "2. Amount of folders at a specified level"
    print "3. Max depth between all the folders"
    op=raw_input()
    if op == "1":
        print "Ingrese directorio"
        d=raw_input()
    if op == "2":
        print "Ingrese nivel"
        n=raw_input()
        compararnivel(n)

raw_input()
```

Comment: 1. Why join all the strings up only to split them up again? A better method would be to initialize l1 as an empty list and append l2 to it
2. Your first while True loop could be better expressed as while l2!='//', and then you don't need an if-else in the loop 
3. Your 2nd while loop does not ever end, so you will never get to the final raw_input block 
4. Most importantly, what exactly is your question now?

Comment: you say i should do l1=[] and l2=raw_input()? The question remains the same I'm only asking for the 2. option in code. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: you could use [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) to manipulate pathnames in a portable manner. Read pathnames in one-line (for educational purposes): [`paths = list(iter(lambda: raw_input("Add path or press Enter"), ''))`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian I did suggest that, but it seems the OP has a rather simple assignment. 

Tomás Medina check out my edited answer for some hints on how you can improve your code, I do recommend following the above suggestion to use os.path once you understand the basics though

Comment: @Dhara Thanks man I have seen what you posted, very useful. I definitely need to do more excersise in python to understand better how the language works. I will definitely do so i'm liking this language more than c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the user enters the entire path name, and there are no relative paths etc., you can simply use [str.count](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) as follows:

```
>>> str.count('/home/usr/music', '/')
3
```

If however you do need to manipulate the paths to first get them into the full path format, and/or do path validation, take a look at the functions provided in [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)

Ok, so here is some code explaining my comments:

1. You can add the raw_input data to a list instead of joining it to a string and splitting it up as follows:

   ```
   l1 = [] # This makes an empty list
   l2 = raw_input("> ") # Do this statement in a loop if you like
   l1.append(l2) # This appends l2 to the list
   ```
2. The while loop can be better expressed as follows:

   ```
   while l2!='//':
     append l2 to the list
     prompt the user for more input
   ```
3. You should add an end condition to your 2nd while loop, perhaps by adding a 4th prompt asking the user to quit

Putting all this together, you get the following (Note my comments, they should help you)

```
print "Please add paths, enter // to stop" # It is a good idea to tell the user how to stop the input process

l1 = [] # Create empty list
l2 = raw_input('> ') # Ideally, you should verify that the user entered a valid path (eg: are '/' allowed at the end of a path?)

while l2 != '//':
    l1.append(l2)
    l2 = raw_input('> ')

print "Your paths are: "
for path in l1:
    print path

# I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with "print l1[1].count("/")" so leaving it out

# I would suggest to print the options outside the loop, it's a matter of taste, 
# but do you really want to keep printing them out?
print "Choose an option: \n\
       1. Number of subfolders of path\n\
       2. Number of folders at a specific path\n\
       3. Max depth between all folders\n\
       4. Quit\n"

choice = raw_input('Enter choice: ')

while choice!='4':
    if choice == '1':
        path = raw_input('Which path are you looking for?')
            # Calculate and print the output here

    # This is the question you asked, so I am answering how to process this step    
    if choice == '2':
        level = raw_input('Which level? ') # Ideally, you should verify that the user indeed enters an int here

        # Since your python does not seem to be very advanced, let's use a simple for loop:
        num=0
        for path in l1:
            if str.count(path, '/')==int(level):
                num = num+1

        print 'Number of such paths is: ', num

    if choice == '3':
        print 'this is not yet implemented'
        # Do something

    choice = raw_input('Enter choice: ')
```

Comment: **-1**: *`TypeError`: slice indices must be integers or `None` or have an `__index__` method*

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment? The code I provided gives this exception for you? It works fine on my copy of python 2.7

Comment: Aah, I see your problem: did you redefine the built-in type 'str' to a string? Try the code again without assigning anything to 'str'. I would appreciate it if you remove the down-vote if this is the case

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I hadn't realized you could access it through `str.count`, `string.count`, and `"string".count`.

Comment: man I don't know what to say other than thank you very much. Yes my python is pretty basic I decided to start learning it with this problem. I had previous knowledge on some of the basics but not at the scope of this problem.
Now my last question is how can I print the paths that are in the level? Thank you very much again first time that i have found a internet community that has helped me this much.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.count(substring)`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), which counts the number of times a sequence appears in the string.

```python
paths = [
    '/home/user/music',
    '/home/user/photos',
    '/home/user/research',
    '/home/user/music/rock'
]

level = 3

wantedPaths = [path for path in paths if path.count('/') == level]
print wantedPaths
```

Comment: Could you explain, why do you import `itertools` at the beginning? Maybe you wanted to use some part of it later?

Comment: @Tadeck: Whoops. Left from where I was using `itertools.groupby` before I read the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
strings = [
    '/home/user/music',
    '/home/user/photos',
    '/home/user/research',
    '/home/user/music/rock',
]

def slash_counter(n):
    return lambda x: x.count('/') == n

n = int(raw_input('Gimme n: '))

for path in filter(slash_counter(n), strings):
    print path
```